# Task blocked when moving / resizing window

Tags: c#, multithreading, mvvm, observablecollection, ui-thread

I have a simple view model that contains a modified `ObservableCollection` which uses `SynchronizationContext.Current.Send` to execute changes to the collection on the UI thread. This collection is populated by a long running background thread.

This is working fine in all the different ways I've tried doing this, however they all seem to be blocked while moving the window or resizing it.

[image]
The gaps in this plot are from pressing and holding the mouse button on the window's title bar.

Different methods I've attempted

Task.Factory.StartNew:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                double y = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    Values.Add(new ValuePoint(DateTime.Now, Math.Sin(y)));
                    y += 0.1;
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                }
            });
```

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(GenerateNumbers);

private void GenerateNumbers(object obj)
    {
        double y = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Values.Add(new ValuePoint(DateTime.Now, Math.Sin(y)));

            y += 0.1;                
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
    }
```

new Thread:

```
_valueSimThread = new Thread(GenerateNumbers);
_valueSimThread.IsBackground = true;
_valueSimThread.Start();
```

Have I misunderstood something here? My expectations is that work being done in the thread should not be affected by stuff I do on the UI thread. Is it the action of using `SynchronizationContext.Current.Send` to update the collection the source of my problem?

What is the correct "pattern" for having an `ObservableCollection` that is updated by a background task?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it the action of using SynchronizationContext.Current.Send to
>   update the collection the source of my problem?

Yes, it is. `SynchronizationContext.Send` will end up posting the delegate to your UI thread. While you're moving your screen, the UI is pumped with many message regarding the new location of your window, mouse clicks, etc. So eventually, you're queuing up work to the UI thread, which is currently occupied.

As long as you're using some sort of collection which is bound to the UI, you have no other way then to queue work onto that UI message loop.